# Count elements of array via pointers in other array

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I'm trying to count the elements in array a or b, by using their reference in array x. So far this is what I have:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int b[]={0,2,4,5};

int* x[]={a,b};

//These work as expected
int count_elements_a= sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); // returns 5
int count_elements_b= sizeof(b)/sizeof(int); // returns 4
int count_elements_x= sizeof(*x)/sizeof(int); // returns 2
```

I can get the value of a final position of array a via x no problem:

```
int a2 = x[0][2]; // returns 3
```

But now, I want to count elements of a, via x and can't seem to figure it out:

```
//Count elements of a, via x. Should return 5.
int count_elements_ax= sizeof(*x[0])/sizeof(int); // returns 1
int count_elements_ax1= sizeof(x[0])/sizeof(int); // returns 2
```

Comment: Why put yourself through all this? Can you not use a `std::vector`, for example, and just use `.size()`?

Comment: In short, you can't. That information is lost when `a` and `b` decay to pointers during the initialisation of `x`.

Comment: Think of it. What is the type of `x[0]`? It is `int*`. The `sizeof(int*)` can only be one thing for a given program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to count elements of `a` if you have access to `x` and no access to `a`. By the time `a` is in `x`, it is simply a pointer; the information about it being in array is no longer available to the compiler.

A common trick in situations like this is to use a separate array of lengths:

```
size_t len[] = {count_elements_a, count_elements_b};
```

Of course this applies only to built-in arrays. C++ standard library provides `std::vector` container which lets you find out array size by calling a member function.